# Add elements to datatable

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm using angular-datatables and wondering how could I add various elements such as buttons, text inputs etc to already rendered and set datatable. I think it may be possible through new angular directive and link function, e.g.:

```
link = (scope, element, attrs) =>
        $('#table_wrapper div.top').append(some nice custom element)
```

this directive is taking place in the parent div:

```
<div my-custom-directive>
                    <table id="table" datatable="ng" ... etc
```

The problem is datatable building elements such as 'table_wrapper' and others are not ready yet when I try to add my new custom elements to them.

Comment: You will want to use the datatables API to build your datatable. That way you know when the table is built to add your elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way as I see to handle that problem is:

angular-datatables has a directive called **dt-instance**:

< table id="table" datatable="ng" dt-instance="yourCallback",

where callback is a function wherein among other useful things you can set a control flag in the scope, so in my controller i have:

```
yourCallback: (dtInstance) =>
    $scope.flag= 1
```

next in my-custom-directive I watch this flag:

```
link = (scope, element, attrs) =>
    scope.$watch('flag', (newval, oldval) =>
            if (newval)
                 $('#table_wrapper div.top').append(some nice custom element)
```